# Scopes Output in Token

Tags: openid, openiddict

I am moving our Identity Server from IDSRv4 to Openiddict and have a strange "issue"

The tokens produced by IdentityServerV4 store the scopes in an array, whilst the ones produced in Openiddict are storing them in a string. when accessing these scopes using RequireClaim this RequireCliam cannot seem to process the difference in the token scopes.

Would anyone be aware of a method to force Openiddict to output these as an array?

I have tried manually adding them to a new claim called scope, however this seems to be being ignore and I end up with a claim called scope with the value openid

Comment: Where do you try to use these? I'm new to openiddict too, but see the scopes in the claims array as "oi_scp". You could try to check for **builder.RequireClaim(OpenIddict.Abstractions.OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Private.Scope, "api");**

Comment: I'm trying to use it when reading a bearer token, in a separate application, but I think that JWT token style has been updated

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. It took me quie a few hours to figure out but here is my solution:

Create a cusom handler:

```cs
public class ScopesAsArrayHandler : IOpenIddictServerHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.GenerateTokenContext>
{
    public ValueTask HandleAsync(OpenIddictServerEvents.GenerateTokenContext context)
    {
        // backup OpenIdDict's custom scope claims
        var scopes = context.Principal.GetClaims("oi_scp"); 

        // remove OpenIdDict's custom scope claims
        context.Principal.RemoveClaims("oi_scp");

        // add backed up scopes as "scope" claims
        context.Principal.AddClaims("scope", scopes);

        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and register the handler in the .AddServer() section in the Program.cs (or Startup.cs):

```cs
builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(...)
    .AddServer(opts => {
        ...
        opts.AddEventHandler<OpenIddictServerEvents.GenerateTokenContext>(b =>
        {
            b.UseSingletonHandler<ScopesAsArrayHandler>();
            // make sure this is executed before weird stuff is done with the scopes
            b.SetOrder(int.MinValue);
        });
     })
     .AddValidation(...);
```

Now you can use OpenIdDict's extension method(s) `principal.SetScopes(...)` to set the scopes in your /connect/authorize.

Comment: You might need to remove scope claim as well: `context.Principal.RemoveClaims("scope");` without this I couldn't use `offline_access` scope